# How can I properly resize a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
let a = localStorage.getItem('homeview');
if(a == null || a == 100){return;}
else{$('#panelb').width(a + '%');}
```

So `panelb` is resized if `homeview` is set and below `100`.

But this happens very late, because `panelb` is first full width (100%) and after a few of seconds - resizing works. However, this doesn't look professional. Is there a better approach to hide a `div`?

The above code is at the end of page. I tried to put it inside `head` tag, and inside `document.ready` function - nothing helps.

Is there a way to detect `homeview` variable before css is loaded and place its value inside css?

Comment: Maybe set the panel to `display:none` and show it when localStorage returns to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then you can use hide function using

```
$('#panelb').hide();
```

Comment: what a perfect solution ! Maybe better - `panelb` shouldn't exists anymore